# Code to copy file when it reaches certain size and move it to directory

Tags: c#, .net

We have developer code that uses log 4 net. It creates new file when it reaches 500 MB. This code creates only two files of 500 MB. Therefore, at point of time there are only two log files. We cannot change this code, as it is not visible. When application starts, it creates file named as 1.log. When it reaches 500 MB, program creates file as 1_1.log. Now, there are two file on disk. Therefore, program will overwrite first file. Therefore, at point of time, I have only two files. As the code is not visible, I cannot change this program.
But, I want to write another piece of code in C# that will copy these files to some directory  when it reaches certain MB. Therefore, I can have more log files.

Comment: How about using [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) instead of rolling your own thing?

Comment: There are two piece of code. One is developer code that we cannot change. Now as a tester, I want to write C# code that will copy developer log files when it reaches certain size. This utility will run in the background without any manual intervention. So tester will get more log files, because developer code creates only two log files and then starts overwriting it.

Comment: Is the 500MB limit is "hard coded" in the developer piece code? If it uses Log4Net then most probably it is configured in the config file, that you can change easily. In case if it is hard coded, send the developer to attend some "Better coding Practices" training :-)

Comment: You can write the [windows service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) to monitor the folder for size of the file as soon as second file created you can move the first file and after creating second file move the first file

Answer (score 0):

To sum up:

- Two log files 1.log and 1_1.log
- 1_1.log is a copied version of 1.log when it reaches size above 500
  MB
- 1 log is smaller than 500 MB
- Aim is to copy the bigger file somewhere and archive it

I believe the best solution if you cannot modify this mechanism is creating a windows service. This service should observe the directory where log files are placed and when the file 1_1.log is created it should rename it to 1_current_date.log (or copy it with this name to another folder).